# Use comma values as datapoints within a PieChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using HighCharts and I want to be able to use comma values as data input. 
The standard approach of Highcharts is to create a Piechart by using for example the following datapoints:

```
data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 0.1
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 0.5
        }]
```

Via an external source I retrieve my data (dutch annotation instead of US-us) as follows:

```
data: [{
            name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
            y: 0,1
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 0,5
        }]
```

This wil not work because Highcharts can not handle this because it interperates the y points as two values.

Does anyone knows a solution how I could use comma as data y input points perhaps by using a formatter?

For a demo see this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e9719gca/)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible as the statement there would be interpreted as a comma separated expression (which would result in an error due to bad object formation). If it's possible, try to get your data from the source as a string. Then it becomes a simple matter of using `String.replace` to replace the commas with dots. If you are getting this from a JSON API then that structure would not be a valid JSON (the comma separated value must be wrapped in quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the comma value with a dot value by using replace and parsing it into a float:

```
y: parseFloat(('1,5').replace(/\,/g, '.'))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y30ktm2a/

Answer (score 1):

Hi I am not sure what is your aim if you would like see on tooltip than you set below code before initialize chart you can find [Internationalization](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting)

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
lang: {
    decimalPoint: ','
}
});
```

**Edited for working code**

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
lang: {
    decimalPoint: ','
}
});
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares January, 2015 to May, 2015'
},
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',        
    data: [{
        name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
        y: parseFloat(('1,5').replace(/\,/g, '.'))
    }, {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: parseFloat(('4').replace(/\,/g, '.'))
    }]
}]
});
```

Comment: I will send you jsfiddle link